# Geomesa: How to calculate last coordinate in area for each cam device?

Tags: geomesa

I am trying to find the last coordinate for all cams in area in area at time interval:

```
"1 = 1 AND cam IN ('930e74d9-a607-4345-807a-eea117f97935','2da5186c-73f4-42bd-b1cf-40229673e3cf') 
AND BBOX(geo, 36.29196166992188, 55.36506387240321, 38.92868041992188, 56.114170062223856) 
AND (time >= 2022-02-02T12:00:00+03:00) AND (time <= 2022-02-02T15:00:00+03:00)"
```

for this I found all cameras in query through enumeration. Then I try to find minMax time for each camera distinct.

```
  public CameraStat getCamerasStatistics(GeoQuery geoQueries) {

    CameraStat cameraStatistic = new CameraStat();

    for (String s : geoQueries.getQs()) {
      AccumuloGeoMesaStats stats = ((AccumuloDataStore) dataStore).stats();

      s = queryParser.convertToCorrectTime(s);

      Option<EnumerationStat<Object>> enumeration = null;
      try {
        enumeration = stats.getEnumeration(
            SimpleFeatureUtils.TYPE, "cam", ECQL.toFilter(s), true);
      } catch (CQLException e) {
        log.error("Error",e);
      }

      scala.collection.mutable.Map<Object, Object> camerasCount = enumeration.get()
          .enumeration();

      Map<Object, Object> map = JavaConversions.mapAsJavaMap(camerasCount);

      int size = map.size();
      Integer sum = map.values().stream().map(it -> ((Long) it).intValue()).reduce(0,
                                                                                   Integer::sum);
      Set<String> collect = map.keySet().stream().map(it -> (String) it).collect(
          Collectors.toSet());

      cameraStatistic.addCameraCount(size);
      cameraStatistic.addCoordinatesCount(sum);
      cameraStatistic.addCameras(collect);
    }
    return cameraStatistic;
  }
```

The problem is that geomesa not persist enumeration stats for accumulo. Is it only way to calculate camera enumeration for each query?

from geomesa code: org.locationtech.geomesa.index.stats.MetadataBackedStats

```
  // note: enumeration stats aren't persisted, so we don't override the super method
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GeoMesa there is not currently an option to persist or pre-calculate enumerations; generally they would be too large to store efficiently.

You might explore persisting them separately, or using a local cache such as [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained).